# How to use two let variables in an if statement in swift

Tags: swift, if-statement

I am trying to code an if statement to display text on my label but I want to use two text field variables. It shows no error but when I press the button on the simulator or device the label still shows up blank.

I am just starting coding so I'm guessing it has an easy answer.

Here is my coding:

```
   @IBOutlet var LblResult: UILabel!
   @IBAction func Calculate(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    let Variable1 = (Variable1.text! as NSString).floatValue 

  *//var 1 and 2 are text fields*

    let Variable2 = (Variable2.text! as NSString).floatValue

    if Variable1 > 15 && Variable2 < 30{
        LblResult.text = "TEXT"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing it like this in Swift.

```
if let text1 = CGFloat(variable1.text!), let text2 = CGFloat(variable2.text!), text1 > 15, text2 < 30 {
    lblResult.text = "TEXT"
}
```

A few things to note

- variables should be in *lowerCamelCase*.
- `text` from `UITextField` can be force-unwrapped. They always return at least "".
- Use `String` instead of `NSString` in Swift.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works great!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
// Using a guard statement is a safe way to unwrap optionals
guard let text1 = Variable1.text else { return }
guard let text2 = Variable2.text else { return }

if (Float(text1) > 15) && (Float(text2) < 30) {
    LblResult.text = "TEXT"
}
```